# UISearchController can't set delegate to self

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to get a `UISearchController` working in my navigation bar using `swift3`

I currently have it so a search icon exists in the top right corner.  When you click on the icon, it will show you the `UISearchController`.

The problem is, when I try to do `searchController.delegate = self`, I get an error saying

> Cannot assign value of type 'ParentViewController' to type 'UISearchControllerDelegate'?

I'm assuming since I can't set the delegate, none of the actions are linked, but I can't figure out why it won't let me?

Here's the code I'd like to work.  Am I implementing the protocol wrong and just not seeing it, or missing something entirely?

```
class ParentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

var searchBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    searchBarButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print("update search results")
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("search cancelled")
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    print("Filter: " + searchText)
}


@IBAction func startSearchAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Clicked")

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

    definesPresentationContext = true

    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(nil, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Your class needs to conform to `UISearchControllerDelegate` - add it to the list of protocols in the class definition or add it via an extension

Comment: Sweet, that solved the seachController.delegate = self problem.  None of the actions are happening still though??  I thought it would be able to reach those once the protocol was right?

Comment: What actions exactly? I don't see any `UISearchControllerDelegate` functions in your code above.

Comment: The searchBarCancelButtonClick is part of the UISearchBarDelegate.searchBar which is also set in the code above, but I was originally thinking nothing was working since the main delgate wasn't set.    I don't actually see a cancel action within UISeachControllerDelgate, only UISearchBarDelegate.searchBar

Comment: Yea sorry, your original question was talking about `UISearchController` and not the search bar so that was my confusion. So when you tap the cancel button that function isn't being called still?

Comment: Ya, it's still not being called.  Sorry that's totally my bad on that, I kinda transitioned into another question rather than re-posting this one with the same code but different question.

Comment: It looks like I was missing a searchController.isActive = yes.   Now it's working as expected!

Comment: Good to hear that!